# TYPO3, Extbase and use web services instead of database

Tags: typo3, extbase

Supposed you need to interact with/integrate 5+ different web service sources instead of tables from the database.
In first lane each WS supports read methods like search,list and single view (in short, no CUD from CRUD). Write access should also take place later.

What would be your approach to integrate those to extbase?

I'd like to stick to the conventions of models and repositories. In this case, i think we need to use Models and CustomRepositories. Should the repositories interact directly with the webservice or should we think bigger with an PersistenceManagerInterface implementation and extending the Generic/Query to e.g. paginate on the results by extbase conventions? What is about TypeConverters and PropertyMappers for linking between controller actions with the models "as parameters".

How could a mapping from JSON to the models look like? A TCA configuration is required for the DataMapper, but this is not available because no DB is used, so it cannot be used.

Where should you start?

Comment: Asking for "best practice" is not asking for fact and is considered opinion which will get your question closed. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: Damn, i don't like thoose restrictions. I am very interested in an answer about this, too!

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282661/typo3-webservice-rest-api-as-repository-for-extbase-extension